# What is the purpose of the `daemon` group and user on RHEL/CentOS Linux?

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am on CentOS 6.5 and about to add a service to the system with `chkconfig`. It will run with its own system account, let's call it (the account) `foobar`, but I do not see the point of also creating the `foobar` group with it. I am contemplating making the account have `daemon` as its primary login group, because it's a service. But before I do, I would really like to know what this `daemon` group (and user!) are all about?

CentOS documentation just lists these in a table, without much additional information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### What is the purpose of the `daemon` group and user?

> The daemon User ID/Group ID was used as an unprivileged User ID/Group ID for daemons to execute under in order to limit their access to the system. **Generally daemons should now run under individual User ID/Group IDs in order to further partition daemons from one another**.

Source [User & Group Names](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/usernames.html)

See also [Why is it recommended to create a group and user for some applications?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29159/why-is-it-recommended-to-create-a-group-and-user-for-some-applications) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

It is there mostly as a legacy thing. The daemon User ID/Group ID was used as an unprivileged User ID/Group ID for daemons to execute under in order to limit their access to the system. Generally daemons should now run under individual User ID/Group IDs in order to further partition daemons from one another.

What it would hurt to use the daemon group though? Probably nothing but it isn't like creating a group has much overhead and you avoid the possibility that something happens to the daemon group somewhere else that impacts your service.